# jQuery code not updating fields in database or updating dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I know that the PHP scripts work because I tested them without jQuery therefore I think something wrong with my jQuery.

```
<form id="bakery" name="bakery" method="POST" action="bakeryupdate.php">
            <select id="bakeryid" name="bakeryid">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                </select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="bakeryupdatebutton" />
</form>

$(document).ready(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'bakeryupdate.php',
        data: {bakeryid:bakeryid}
        }).done(function(){
            $('#success').text('success!');

        });
    }
        e.preventDefault();
        });    
});
```

update data php script

```
<?php       
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $sql = "UPDATE bakeryorders SET description='shipped";

        if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {

            echo "Bakery order updated";
        } else {
            echo "Error!";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Any error in error console?

Comment: No errors not showing the selections in options, there should be 4 selections (i tried when i put the selection options code in the form) and when i submit it says success! but doesn't add to database and no errors for this either :(

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string()` requires DB connection be passed. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php - Plus, make sure your submit button has the name attribute. That conditional statement is relying on it.

Comment: Add `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()` and use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - You have enough to debug your code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- `$bakeryid= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['bakeryid'])` ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I do have` $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bakery") or die(mysqli_error($con));
      
    //check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error ();
    }`

Comment: @Fred-ii- still not working or showing any errors!

Comment: You've been given an answer below. Commenting back and forth here will result in being too chatty. You've been given tools to debug, and use `var_dump()` to see what's passing through or not.

Comment: im not very good debugging i've tried but it's just not doing anything!!

Comment: in google chrome network it's saying OK for everything!

Comment: mysqlcommit doesn't do anything!!!!!!!

Comment: Check the error.log for your server.

Comment: @JayBlanchard script 'C:/xampp/htdocs/bakerywebsite/bakeryform.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://localhost/bakerywebsite/bakeryform.php

Comment: Alrighty, now you're headed somewhere.

Comment: i've removed the retriving script and posted the selectoptions code in my form just so i can make it update in the database first and its not showing any errors why is it doing this ? pleas e help me

Comment: You want to inspect the output if you are to start narrowing down where the error is. In your update script, just return $sql and inspect for errors. If it looks good, try to copy and paste into what you are using to manage your db (phpmyadmin, workbench, etc). If it doesn't work the way you want it to (ie no rows affected, or returns an error) then you've nailed down your problem.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with my php script it works without the jqeuery it updates everything. ive added the jquery to make it dynamic without having to refresh every time but it's not updating when i click submit. @frost287

Comment: What I'm getting at is how to debug your code. start from what you know works and move up from there. Your php code may work by itself but there may be something preventing it from running correctly. That's why you want to inspect the output in a non-testing environment to see whats wrong. If your script is returning the success message, then that means whatever your database is receiving as a query isn't returning an error. an update query WHERE some_column='non_existent_value' could update zero rows and not return an error because the syntax didn't fail.

Comment: @frost287 I've fixed the success message now , my jquery wasn't right, isntead of passing the data i just passed the form, trying to get the retrieve for options to work

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to `commit` the transaction if you don't have autocommit...

```
mysqli->commit();
```